# Backbone fetch multiple collections to a single collection

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, promise, jquery-deferred

I have two collections that I want to merge into one single collection, and I don't want to use jquery `$.when(A.fetch(), B.fetch())` because `$.when` will execute failed callback as soon as one of the parameter fails which i don't want if one of them successful that I still want to render with it.

The following is the way I came out with. I am wondering is there an alternative way of doing it, and can we do it simultaneously without some race condtion ?

```
A.fetch().then(function(json) {
     addToMyCollection(json);
}).always(function() {
      B.fetch().then(function(json){ 
           addToMyCollection(json);
      }).always(function() {
           renderViewWithMyCollection();
      });
});
```

Comment: Is using a better promise library an option? jQuery deferreds are a really minimalistic (and pretty crippled) implementation.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to take advantage of Backbone.Events :

```
var inject = function(collection) {
  C.add(collection.models)
}

A.on('sync', inject)
B.on('sync', inject)

C.on('add', function() { /* render c */ })

A.fetch()
B.fetch()
```

If you want to merge only once, use `once` instead of `on`

One key difference between the above code and your implementation is that render will happen twice, so once the first collection has synced, the items of first collection are rendered, and when both have synced all the items are rendered.

If you want to prevent this from happening you can keep a counter, increment it after adding items to C and check it before rendering c.

Answer (score 1):

Unlike in sequential code, you can wait for promise after you invoke it.

```
var pA = A.fetch();
var pB = B.fetch();
pA.then(function(json){
     addToMyCollection(json); 
}).always(function(){ // in better impls, finally
     pB.then(function(res){
         addToMyCollection(res);
     }).always(function(){
         renderViewWithMyCollection();
     });
});
```

Or, more compactly;

```
var pA = A.fetch(), pB = b.fetch();
pA.then(addToMyCollection).always(function(){
      return pB.then(addToMyCollection);
}).always(renderViewWithMyCollection);
```

You can wrap this "finished" with:

```
function always(promise){
     return promise.then(null,function(){}); // ignore rejection
}
```

And then do:

```
$.when(always(A.fetch().then(addToMyCollection)),
       always(B.fetch().then(addToMyCollection))).
 then(renderViewWithMyCollection());
```

Of course, real promise libraries like Bluebird have this sort of functionality built in.